# System Optimization software for Windows

Tags: windows, optimization, maintenance, windows-registry

I would like to have a software which performs PC optimization in various ways such as...

- Registry CleanUp
- Registry Degragmentation
- Uninstall Programs
- Disable Startup Programs
- Disable Inactive Programs
- Cleaning Up Temporary Files
- Clean Up Browsers
- Defragmentation
- Check Hard Disk for Errors

---

**Additional Requirements** (Not compulsory, but good if the software have these options)

- Auto Maintenance/Optimization
- Auto Prioritization of Applications
- Notifying Software which causes load on the System

Comment: @MrAllen This may also meet your requirements http://www.iobit.com/advancedsystemcareper.html

Comment: @Simon You can always post your suggestions as answers :)

Comment: Thats true :) I shall do it later or tomorrow (at the latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software that would match requirements the best is [TuneUp Utilities](http://www.tune-up.com/download/)...

It has too many features which will keep your system clean... The only thing you need to look for it, is that it's premium..

Some Screens

[image: TuneUp Utilities Dashboard]

[image: TuneUp Utilities All Functions]

### Features

**Performance**

- User Interface
- Program Deactivator
- Startup Manager
- Live Optimization
- Drive Defrag
- Turbo Mode
- StartUp Optimizer
- Performance Optimizer
- Optimization status
- Rating Function for Programs

---

**PC CleanUp**

- Disk Cleaner
- Windows 8.1 App Cleaner
- Automatic Cleaning Updates
- Duplicate Finder
- Browser Cleaner
- Disk Space Explorer
- Uninstall Manager
- Shortcut Cleaner
- Shredder
- Registry Cleaner & Registry Defrag

---

**Analysis**

- Disk Doctor
- Repair Wizard
- Undelete
- Process Manager
- Status & Recommendations
- System Information

---

**Power Up**

- Flight Mode
- Economy Mode

---

**Automatic**

- Automatic Cleaning Updates
- 1-Click-Maintenance & Automatic Maintenance

---

**Tweaker**

- Styler
- System Control
- Optimization Report
- Settings Center
- Overview of all functions

---

As far as Freeware goes, I would recommend using [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/). Won't cover the features extensively like TuneUp Utilities but it's free, and is good to optimize your PC.. Especially for Home Users...

[Features of CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/features)

Basically this software cleans up the browsers you've installed, like Cache, Temporary Files, History etc...

Apart from that, it does have few optimization features like Registry Cleanup, Cleaning up Windows Temporary Files, DNS Cache, Memory Dumps etc...

Comment: Adding [CCEnhancer](http://singularlabs.com/software/ccenhancer/) to CCleaner more than triples the number of areas for CCleaner to look for temp files

Answer (score 1):

We're in the same boat, since I have a 3 year old dell laptop that's really starting to show its age with super slow startup. I've been using a free program called Baidu PC Faster to speed it up.

First time I used this it claimed to boost my speed by 124%! A little weird -- I don't know how accurate that number is, but I could definitely feel a noticeable difference in my laptop's performance and boot up speed. Even if you know how to manually clear out your browser cache, etc, this app does it for you all in one place, which is actually really convenient.